# Can the word 'destiny' be used in English in reference to the past?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can the word 'destiny' be used in English in reference to the past?

A teacher (not a native English speaker) gave my son the following written task:

> Think about Taiwan's **destiny** from Dutch period to Cheng's family period (to describe at least 40 words)

Here she is referring to two periods of history of Taiwan, but she uses the word 'destiny'.

I took it as "describe what kind of destiny Taiwan was facing during that time" or "describe what kind of destiny Taiwan would have run into", but I myself am not an English speaker, so I may be wrong.

Later my wife told me that most likely the teacher simply wanted my son to describe the general situation in Taiwan during that specified time in the past. My wife said that the Chinese word that the teacher most likely had on her mind while writing 'destiny' fits perfectly well into a sentence about the past in Chinese. In other words, the Chinese word for "destiny" can mean the situation (an inevitable one) in the future, as well as some specific situation in the past (often an undesirable one, a kind of plight).

I wonder if it's also the case with the word 'destiny' in English? Was the teacher's usage of the word "destiny' correct in that sentence? Would a native English speaker also use the word 'destiny' in that case or at lease not be confused as much as I was?

EDIT: I DID check the word 'destiny' in a dictionary before posting this question, but the dictionary doesn't say anything about whether or not I can use this word to refer to a situation in the past.

Comment: Have you looked for 'destiny' in a dictionary?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Of course, I did. But dictionaries don't say much about the usage.

Comment: I think for a situation in the past, "fate" would fit better.

Comment: @Jack - But would that still refer to the future (the future that would have been then) or merely to a situation that took place in the past?

Comment: I believe it can refer to the past. "What was its fate?" can mean "What happened to it?", from the viewpoint of a final summary and explanation. What was the fate of the Roman Empire?" From a viewpoint earlier in time, you could say that what happened was its destiny. But these are my feelings about usage, not really hard definitions.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty - In your examples you are still separating the past into two pasts: the one earlier and the one that happened later. My question, however, can I use that word to simply refer to one past? In other words, can I say "Describe the destiny of India 20 years ago" to simply mean "Describe the situation in India 20 years ago"?

Comment: @brilliant  I would not use it so. I would use simply "situation". Ether "destiny" or "fate", would refer to a final determination, rather than a contemporary description of the situation.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty - I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although without qualification, 'destiny' means 'fate' or 'final state', it is possible to use the word 'destiny' to discuss events that are now in the past, but which were in the future at some past time.

> A sweeping historical narrative examines the personalities, events,
>   and political maneuvers that shaped Japan's destiny during the years
>   of World War II
>
> China's destiny during the first half of the century.
>
> a series of meetings between Chiang and Nehru which were of importance
>   to China's destiny during the war with Japan

Comment: In all three examples that you provided the word 'destiny' refers to the events 'that are now in the past, but which were in the future at some past time'. But my question is can I use that word to simply refer to the past? In other words, can I say "Describe the destiny of India 20 years ago" to simply mean "Describe the situation in India 20 years ago"?

Comment: No, that would not be a suitable use. A destiny in that sense happens after something.

Comment: I see. Thank you.